# How can i add onto the linked list for best fit management or delete something?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am having trouble with linked list best fit memory management. I created the linked list and add the first element , but it does not add anything else after. It basically avoids my else statement. If anyone can give me a concept on how to do it or if i am doing anything wrong, it would be great if you let me know!

```
unsigned int MaxMem = 400000000;
struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *next;
    struct PCB *prev;
    int PID;
    unsigned int PrSize;
    int best;
    unsigned int Begin;
    unsigned int End;
}*node = NULL, *first = NULL, *node1 = NULL, *node2 = NULL;
class linked
{
    public:

        void Mem_begin(PCB a)
        {
            PCB *add = new PCB;
            struct PCB *save;
            int bestfit = -1;
            //add->End = MaxMem;
            add->Begin = a.PrSize;
            add->next = NULL;
            if((first == NULL) && (bestfit1 == -1))
            {
                bestfit = a.ProcessID;
                a.best = bestfit;
                add->prev = NULL;
                first = add;
                cout << first->prev << " - " << first->Begin << " Process " << bestfit << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                save = first;
                while(save->prev != NULL)
                {
                    bestfit = a.PID;
                    a.best = bestfit;
                    save = save->next;
                    save->next = add;
                    add->prev = save;
                    cout << " i did it" << endl;
                }

            }
        }

        void display(PCB a) {
            node = first;
            while(node != NULL)
            {
                cout << node->prev << " - " << node->Begin << " Process " << a.best << endl;
                node = node->next;
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
    PCB test;
    linked try;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "What is the PID?" << endl;
        cin >> test.PID;
        cout << "How much memory space?" << endl;
        cin >> test.PrSize;
        try.Mem_begin(test);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Write your code using std::list, test and make sure that it works. Then, if necessary, re-write it to use your own list implementation. I simply don't understand why so many people, as teachers or students or professionals, think it's a good idea to write their own list class.

Comment: yea but im trying to make a memory best fit , list will be limited in doing so like replacing

Answer (score 1):

When the shown code installs the first element in the linked list:

```
add->prev = NULL;
first = add;
```

The first node's `prev` pointer is `NULL` (`next` is also NULL), and `first` points to the first element.

And when the list is not empty, the logic goes thusly:

```
 save = first;
 while(save->prev != NULL)
```

And, since we've just discussed that the initial node's `prev` pointer is `NULL`, this horse falls flat right out of the starting gate. The `while` loop will never execute, since `first`'s `prev` node will always be `NULL`.

The intent of your overall logic is somewhat unclear, but at least this answers you question why "it does not add anything else after."